# Disable Command-W Everywhere

Tags: keyboard

There was a question on [Disable Command-W in the terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44412/disable-command-w-in-the-terminal) but is there a way to determine Command-W globally on MacOS? I keep accidentally closing my applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable CMD+Q combination?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/how-to-disable-cmdq-combination)

Answer (score 3):

```
System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts
```

Just add a new CMD-W shortcut should override the actual behavior.

Edit: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7634486